# Estimating Average Edge Thickness of Edge Drawing

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I am working on a project where I am generating an edge diagram of a face and I need to estimate the average edge thickness of the edges. Below is an example of an image for which I need to compute the average edge thickness:

[image: Face]

My plan is to segment the image into various regions of interest (nose, mouth, left eye, right eye, overall face) and then estimate the average edge thickness for each region.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I am programming this project in C++ using OpenCV, so while all ideas are welcome, C++ and OpenCV solutions are preferred.

Comment: Interesting question, it may be worth asking it over at the DSP stack exchange which has a number of more "algorithmic" questions: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Determining the stroke width is exactly the point in the stroke width transform algorithm, see http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~turkel/imagepapers/text_detection.pdf

While this is for detecting text one step in the algorithm is to find the thickness of an edge. Averaging it might not be the problem.

OpenCV source to adapt is available at https://sites.google.com/site/roboticssaurav/strokewidthnokia